# Devise Bootstrap Views error rendering: couldn't find file 'devise_bootstrap_views' with type 'text/css'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to use the devise bootstrap views gem https://github.com/hisea/devise-bootstrap-views to create an app.

Here is what I did:

1. Added the respective gem 'devise-bootstrap-views' to the Gemfile + bundle install
2. Added `*= require devise_bootstrap_views` to the `application.css` file before `*= require_tree .`
3. Ran the command `rails g devise:views:locale en`
4. Ran the command `rails g devise:views:bootstrap_templates`

However, when I refresh the browser, I see the following error. I tried figuring out the error but to no avail.

Here's the screenshot of the error:

[image]

Could someone tell me where the error is being caused?

Answer (score 5):

I have to remove this line:

```
*= require devise_bootstrap_views
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you missed the server. Did you restart the server?

Answer (score 0):

Install Bootstrap as per https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails
Run bundle install Run the generator **rails generate bootstrap:install static** Restart server.
You now have Bootstrap installed                                                        Next install Devise **gem 'devise'** Run bundle install
Run the generator
*rails generate bootstrap:install static*
Attach Devise to  a Model (Say User) *rails generate devise MODEL*
Restart server.                                                                          You now have Devise installed to a User Object
Install Bootstrap views gem
*'devise-bootstrap-views', '~> 1.0'*                                                     Run bundle install                                                                       Run the generator *rails generate devise:views:bootstrap_templates*
Restart Server

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line, It will work fine.
*= require devise_bootstrap_views