# Devise bootstrap views not found after updating to latest version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I get the following error after updating Devise bootstrap views to the latest version (1.1.0). Everything works OK if I switch back to v0.0.11.

[image]

What is the problem?

In my **Gemfile** I have this

```
gem 'devise'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem "devise-bootstrap-views"
```

**application.css**

```
/*  
 *= require devise_bootstrap_views
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self     
 */
```

**bootstrap_and_overrides.css**

```
/*
  =require twitter-bootstrap-static/bootstrap

  Static version of css will use Glyphicons sprites by default
  =require twitter-bootstrap-static/sprites
*/
```

**application.js**

```
 //
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery

//= require twitter/bootstrap
// require turbolinks


//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick

//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Did you restart the server after update the gem?

Comment: Yes, several times.....

Comment: Have you used  rails g devise:views:locale it ? If not, try it out. Otherwise, is there a specific reason why you went back to an older version?

Comment: The views folder and files are there. It just does not find them. Isn't locale:it supposed to be for Italian?

Comment: Up until yesterday I had v0.0.11 and everything was working fine. Then I did bundle update and I got the problem so I switched back.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I guess this is a duplicate of [Question #52636393](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636393/devise-bootstrap-views-error-rendering-couldnt-find-file-devise-bootstrap-vie).

I had this same problem while updating dependencies from an old project of mine. All I had to do was to remove the following line from `application.css`

```css
 *= require devise_bootstrap_views
```

Look for this line in your css/sass files and try removing it. Oh, and remember to **restart your server** :)

I hope it helps.